# C# Monogame Xamarin build gets stuck randomly in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, monogame

I use **Visual Studio for Mac** on **M1** MacBook Air, specifically targeting Android using Monogame.
The build gets stuck **randomly** and at any point in time, so the first time I build after opening VS, it works fine, the 2nd or 3rd gets stuck, and I can't cancel the build, so I have to close the application and reopen it and start again, and the cycle happens again. If anyone encountered something similar, please share any solution with me

I don't know what I should try to do, since VS get stuck at random during the build, and getting stuck happens randomly too

Comment: Help -> Report a  Problem

Comment: Thank you Jason, I just did that, I hope I get a feedback soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, it turns out that I turned on some features in **Project Properties** which were supposed to be for release mode, that's why somethings took ages to build.

Comment: I will, it just told me that I have to wait 22 hours to do so